# Missing keyword from SELECT CASE

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle10g, case

I am unsure what is wrong with this sequence of case statements. 
I have looked online and the syntax seems to be correct but I am getting the error missing keyword.
Any help would be much appreciated!

```
CASE 
when A = '1' then
         when sequence_number = 5 then 9
         when sequence_number = 6 then 9
         end
 when A = '2' then
       when sequence_number = 5 then 9
       when sequence_number = 6 then 9
       end
  when A = '3' then
        when sequence_number =7 then 9
        when sequence_number =8 then 9
        end
else T.number
end as number
```

Comment: do you need an extra "case" in the dependent case clauses? ie, case when A = '1' then *case* when sequence_number ... etc

Comment: aliasing a column with a reserved word (`number`) is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option would seem to be:

```
 case 
   when (A in (1,2) and sequence_number in (5,6)) or
        (A in (3  ) and sequence_number in (7,8))
   then 9
   else t.number
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

You would either need a second `CASE` statement within each branch or you would need to combine the conditions

```
CASE 
when A = '1' and sequence_number = 5 then 9
when A = '1' and sequence_number = 6 then 9
when A = '2' and sequence_number = 5 then 9
...
else T.number
end as number
```

or

```
CASE 
when A = '1' then
         case when sequence_number = 5 then 9
              when sequence_number = 6 then 9
         end
when A = '2' then
       case when sequence_number = 5 then 9
            when sequence_number = 6 then 9
       end
when A = '3' then
        case when sequence_number =7 then 9
             when sequence_number =8 then 9
        end
else T.number
end as number
```

Answer (score 0):

@mikeb is correct - you need an extra CASE.

I also had trouble with the `Number` column while testing this; just guessing but maybe Oracle is choking on it as a reserved word? If  you, like me, get an `ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification` exception then change it to something like `Num` or `TheNumber`.

Here's the updated CASE:

```
CASE
when A = '1' then
       case
       when sequence_number = 5 then 9
       when sequence_number = 6 then 9
       end
when A = '2' then
       case
       when sequence_number = 5 then 9
       when sequence_number = 6 then 9
       end
when A = '3' then
       case
       when sequence_number =7 then 9
       when sequence_number =8 then 9
       end
else T.number
end as number
```